# Where are WindowEvents fired from?

Tags: java, swing

I have a really weird problem, one of the windows in my app (let's call it "Window A") is consistently placing itself (or being put) *behind* the window that brings it out ("Window B").  Even if I click on Window A, Window B immediately comes forward again.

There's nothing obvious in the code as to why this might be happening.  I can write a `windowActivated()` or `windowDeactivated()`, but by the time they're called the information on *who* actually switched the windows is of course long gone.

How can I get to the point where those events are fired?

Comment: As i can't see any research effort, i'm suggest to google "Java EventListener".

Comment: Have you set `alwaysOnTop` or are you call `toFront` or `requestFocus` or any of its variants?

Comment: @chade, I don't see what EventListener will do for me.  I do have WindowListeners but as I said, the information I need is long gone by the time they're called.  I need to know who is firing those events.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I've looked for these.  I'm also pretty much convinced that it's Window A which is requesting to go behind Window B because it happens even if it's called from Window C, or a menubar menu item.  And no, there are no toBack() calls in my entire codebase.

Comment: *"There's nothing obvious in the code.."* What code? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I would, if I could. There is simply too much damn code to make a _small_ SCCE. The reason I'm asking for this specific information (where do WindowEvents get fired, i.e. put on the event queue) is that this is the only way I can see of solving this problem. I've done everything obvious and I'm not asking for help with my code. _I'm asking for help finding who is firing WindowEvents._ This will get me to the problem(s) in my code. Does no-one know where WindowEvents are fired from?

Comment: Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"I would, if I could."* And if you did, we might become motivated enough about the problem to look into it further. As it is, you have not made the 'minimum effort' that is enough for us to spend our time trying to figure this out (for free). BTW - See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) This definitely seems like one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I get what you're saying and understand the frustration and lack of motivation. I've posted SSCCEs to fora in the past where I thought it was appropriate. This time, as an experienced SE not some kid asking for homework help, my estimation is that's not the case. This is a mature codebase with a lot of inheritance; the 'familiarity cost' for you would be huge. I have _events_ which _someone_ is putting on the AWT queue. By the time they come off the queue, that _someone_ is long gone. I need to find out _who_ is putting them on the queue, then I'll be able to figure out _why_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was causing the bug and thought I'd post it here in case it's of use to others.  I never found an answer to my original question, and I still think it may well have shown me where the bug was coming from.  It certainly *was* non-obvious.

It turns out that if you have a custom focus traversal policy (`Container.setFocusTraversalPolicy(FocusTraversalPolicy)`) *and* its `getFirstComponent()` passes back a component which is not focusable[*], then whenever the window is brought to the front either programmatically or by the user, it will be sent back one step in the z-order hierarchy.

I found the problem by good old brute force: the offending window is part of an inheritance hierarchy like so:

```
  AbstractSuperclass
      /      \
     /        \
BuggyWindow  NonBuggyWindow
```

I made a `ToyWindow` class to also descend from `AbstractSuperclass`.  It didn't have the bug.  I laboriously copied in code from `BuggyWindow` until the bug exhibited.  That was in a long method which is called when the window is first displayed; by successive deletion I arrived at the offending block of code, where a number of widgets have their `isEditable()` and `isEnabled()` set to false.  Since other windows have all their widgets disabled (in View mode), there was obviously more to it than that.  Then I remembered the custom focus traversal policy.

I wrote a toy program with the important elements, and was able to reliably trigger the bug.  I added checks for focusability to all of the methods in my custom focus traversal policy.  Bug go bye-bye.

Thanks to those who responded and I do apologise for the lack of information.  I didn't want to waste people's time by shoving huge amounts of code at you.  It meant you didn't get what you're used to here, and that was unfortunate.

[*] I'm taking non-focusable as `!(isFocusable() && isEnabled())` since I couldn't quickly get sufficient information to understand exactly when a component might be focusable but not enabled (or the other way around), and it was good enough for my purposes.  (Oh, how I wish the JRE would have comments better than e.g. "isFocusable() returns whether this component can be focussed"..."isEnabled() returns whether this component is enabled" -- @#&$!!!)